# How to create struct based properties with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have the following code to generate a property:

Types:

```
types = new Dictionary<string, SpecialType>();
types.Add("Guid", SpecialType.System_Object);
types.Add("DateTime", SpecialType.System_DateTime);
types.Add("String", SpecialType.System_String);
types.Add("Int32", SpecialType.System_Int32);
types.Add("Boolean", SpecialType.System_Boolean);  

generator.PropertyDeclaration(name, generator.TypeExpression(types["DateTime"]), Accessibility.Public);
```

However, I always get an exception when the name of a struct type is the parameter (e.g. *DateTime* or *Guid* - for Guid, I can't even find a proper special type):

> Unsupported SpecialType

```
  at: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeGeneration.CSharpSyntaxGenerator.TypeExpression(SpecialType specialType)
  at: MyProject.CreateProperty(String name, String type)
```

What should I use?

Comment: According to [this](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/SpecialType.cs,5b11a29d644330dc), there's nothing for `Guid`. Your DateTime looks fine though

Comment: @lokusking Do you have any hint why they skipped a ***very basic and common*** data type like `Guid`?

Comment: @Nestor "Basic and common" is not the same thing as "special". The compiler considers a type special only when it has to, because there are situations where it needs to handle that type in a special way.

Comment: @svick The types of Object or String are also very basic and yet they appear in the Special types. Why? And why is Guid so special that it can't be interpreted like the String? And the original question still stands: can I create a property with type Guid?

Comment: @Nestor `object` and `string` have their own keywords and are treated in a special way when generating IL, so it makes sense to me that the compiler considers them special.

Comment: @svick Agreed, the `object` and `string` expressions are keywords so they need special treatment. However, it  seems that neither `DateTime`, nor `Guid` can be generated with that method. Is Roslyn still a beta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create properties based upon the name of the type, so you could create DateTime and Guid properties with code such as

```
// Create an auto-property
var idProperty =
    SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(
        SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("Guid"),
        "Id"
    )
    .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
    .AddAccessorListAccessors(
        SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration).WithSemicolonToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)),
        SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration).WithSemicolonToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))
    );

// Create a read-only property, using a backing field
var createdAtProperty =
    SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(
        SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("DateTime"),
        "CreatedAt"
    )
    .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
    .AddAccessorListAccessors(
        SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(
            SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration,
            SyntaxFactory.Block(
                SyntaxFactory.List(new[] {
                    SyntaxFactory.ReturnStatement(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("_createdAt"))
                })
            )
        )
    );
```

If I've missed something obvious that means that you can't use this sort of syntax, would you please edit your answer and include an executable minimum reproduce case?

(I noticed that the "PropertyDeclaration" method in your sample specifies parameters name, type, accessibility which do not correspond to any "PropertyDeclaration" method signatures on the SyntaxFactory class - is that method one that you've written that *then* calls a SyntaxFactory method?)

Comment: I can use SyntaxFactory, but the result of your example is this: `Guid Id`. No getter, no setter, but I intend to create automatic properties like `Guid Id {get; set;}`. Can I achieve it with the factory? Your other question: the method I use it is from this class: `generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(workspace, LanguageNames.CSharp);`

Comment: There are methods on the PropertyDeclarationSyntax instance returned by PropertyDeclaration such as "AddModifiers" (so that you may make the property public, for example) and "AddAccessorListAccessors" (so that you may add a getter and / or setter).

Comment: I used this code, no setter or getter appeared, very strange: http://pastebin.com/i0pg5qiD

Comment: I've extended my code sample a bit to specify a modifier and a getter to the properties - does that help at all? When I call "idProperty.ToString()" it returns "publicGuidId{get{return_id;}}" which suggests that it's working (depending upon what you're doing with the PropertyDeclarationSyntax instance, you might get a problem if the "_id" reference but hopefully the sample code is enough to help you get going).

Comment: Almost got there, I modified your code with this: `SyntaxFactory.Block(
              SyntaxFactory.List(new[] {
                    SyntaxFactory.EmptyStatement()
                })`. Unfortunately, it creates a non-valid code, as the `get` statement still has curly braces around the semicolon. I have to remove the braces but I don't know how.

Comment: I've tweaked the idProperty in my example to define the property in the "auto-implemented properties" syntax - ie. "{ get; set; }" and now idProperty.ToString() returns "publicGuidId{get;set;}" which seems like what you want. The new code looks similar to what you had in your pastebin sample but it's different enough that the pastebin version doesn't work but the new code in my answer does.

Comment: Thank, it works now :) It seems that the With* methods are not working with Roslyn yet. That's why I assumed it is still a beta...

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for this. It helped me a lot. I was fighting for hours to generate a auto-property with a custom type and finally, I found this post. It works perfectly on .NET Core 1.1 on Linux.  Thanks again.

Comment: how do we assign a default value to a property or a field ?