# Adding new field declaration to class with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

There is some way to add a member to a class with roslyn? I want to add :

```
public int number {get;set;}
```

UPDATE
I used this code:

```
       PropertyDeclarationSyntax o =  
       SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("public  
       System.Windows.Forms.Timer"), "Ticker { get; set; }");

       var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(oldMethod, oldMethod.AddMembers(o));
       newRoot = Formatter.Format(newRoot, new AdhocWorkspace());

       File.WriteAllText(file, newRoot.ToFullString());
```

But the the result is this:

```
   public class ClassChild
{
    public int n;
    private int n2;

    public void method1()
    {
        string c = "";
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

public System.Windows.Forms.TimerTicker { get; set; }
}
```

}

I would like to inline public System.Windows.Forms.TimerTicker { get; set; } with n and n2. How Can I do this ?

Comment: can you extend what do you want to achieve? Create an analyzer\fixer for adding values, or standalone utility (for build process, for.ex.)?

Comment: I want to fix a  class adding new field. In past I succeed in adding  a new statement to a method :
 /MethodDeclarationSyntax updateMethod = oldMethod.AddBodyStatements(ex);

            //var updatedRoot = root.ReplaceNode(oldMethod, updateMethod).NormalizeWhitespace();

I want to do the same thing

Comment: Can you help me ?

Comment: There are other questions on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336712/adding-auto-implemented-property-to-class-using-roslyn , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204875/adding-custom-attributes-to-c-sharp-classes-using-roslyn ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205773/how-to-create-struct-based-properties-with-roslyn did you try them?

Comment: yes I did, but they don't work

Comment: Can you update your question with your existing code example? Even if it does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the code

```
    private PropertyDeclarationSyntax MakeProperty()
    {
        string name = "n";

        // Create an auto-property
        var property =
            SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("int"), name)
            .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
            .AddAccessorListAccessors(
                SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration).WithSemicolonToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)),
                SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration).WithSemicolonToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))
            );

        return property;
    }

    private async Task<Document> AddProperty(Document document, ClassDeclarationSyntax classeDecl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
        var newClass = classeDecl.AddMembers(MakeProperty());
        return document.WithSyntaxRoot(root.ReplaceNode(classeDecl, newClass));
    }
```

Auto property genaration example is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205773/how-to-create-struct-based-properties-with-roslyn) question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer this kind of technique:

```
public static class SyntaxHelpers
{
    public static T GenerateClassNode<T>(string decl) where T : CSharpSyntaxNode
    {
        var declaration = SyntaxFactory.ParseCompilationUnit(
            " public class FSM { \r\n" +
            $"{decl}\r\n" +
            " }} \r\n");

        var field = declaration.Members[0].DescendantNodes().First() as T;
        return field;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as following:

```
string log4NetLoggerDeclaration =
                    "private static readonly log4net.ILog Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);";

var log4NetDeclarationStatement = SyntaxHelpers.GenerateClassNode<FieldDeclarationSyntax>(log4NetLoggerDeclaration);

string declarationString = log4NetLoggerDeclaration.ToString();
```